# How to combine all rows and columns of an excel file into a single cell of another excel file using python?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an Excel 'sample1.xlsx' which has the following details:-

```
    0     1       2
0 Name  Address Phone No.
1  abc   22/2    0154235
2  xyz   12-3    9832033
```

I'm looking for an implementation to remove the header from the above excel file using pandas dataframe:-

```
   0     1       2
0 abc  22/2   0154235
1 xyz  12-3   9832033
```

Thereafter, combine all rows and columns to a single cell with a space in between the elements and write the output to another excel file:-

```
                  0
0 abc 22/2 0154235 xyz 12-3 9832033
```

Can anyone help me in the above implementation?

I had already implemented the below code for removing the header,

```
import pandas
excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel('sample.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
df = excel_data_df.iloc[3:]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need not read the headers `header=None` and using [`df.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to stack the dataframe and transpose back:

```
pd.read_excel('file.xlsx',header=None,
    skiprows=[0]).stack().to_frame().reset_index(drop=True).T
```

Similarly using [`df.to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) convert to np array and using  [`np.flatten()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=np+flatten&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=np+flatten&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.1743j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) we can create a dataframe and transpose:

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('file.xlsx').to_numpy().flatten()).T
```

---

```
     0     1       2    3     4        5
0  abc  22/2  154235  xyz  12-3  9832033
```

Comment: What does .T stands for?

Comment: @AmanpreetKhurana it is used for transposing the dataframe check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) , did it work by the way?

Comment: It is giving the values in different rows whereas I'm looking for an implementation to give the resulting values in just first column and first row i.e. at (0,0) - the very first cell of the excel.

Comment: @AmanpreetKhurana can you try `pd.read_excel('file.xlsx',header=None,
    skiprows=[0]).stack().to_frame().reset_index(drop=True).T.astype(str).agg(' '.join,1)`

Comment: This is adding a '0' at location (0,0), rest values get appended at (0,1).

Comment: @AmanpreetKhurana because you are not passing `index=False` when doing a `df.to_csv` , try with `index=False` under `df.to_csv(....,index=False)` , if it works , please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the answer since the question is solved